# How to hide the multiple taxonomy values in WordPress website?

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy

Actually I have 4 different area taxonomies:

`privateschool_area, hospitals_area, therapy_area, salonsandsaps_area`.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="col-lg-6 footerArea">     
    <h3>Area</h3>
    <?php
        $taxonomy     = 'privateschools_area';
        $orderby      = 'name';
        $show_count   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
        $pad_counts   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
        $hierarchical = 1;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
        $title        = '';
        $empty        = 0;

        $args1 = array(
            'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
            'orderby'      => $orderby,
            'show_count'   => $show_count,
            'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
            'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
            'title_li'     => $title,
            'hide_empty'   => $empty
        );              
    ?>
    <?php
        $taxonomy     = 'hospitals_area';
        $orderby      = 'name';
        $show_count   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
        $pad_counts   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
        $hierarchical = 1;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
        $title        = '';
        $empty        = 0;

        $args2 = array(
            'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
            'orderby'      => $orderby,
            'show_count'   => $show_count,
            'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
            'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
            'title_li'     => $title,
            'hide_empty'   => $empty
        );          
    ?>
    <?php       
        $taxonomy     = 'therapy_area';
        $orderby      = 'name';
        $show_count   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
        $pad_counts   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
        $hierarchical = 1;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
        $title        = '';
        $empty        = 0;

        $args3 = array(
            'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
            'orderby'      => $orderby,
            'show_count'   => $show_count,
            'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
            'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
            'title_li'     => $title,
            'hide_empty'   => $empty
        );              
    ?>            
    <?php wp_list_categories( $args1 ); ?>
    <?php wp_list_categories( $args2 ); ?>
    <?php wp_list_categories( $args3 ); ?>
    <?php wp_list_categories( $args4 ); ?>
    </ul>                
</div>
```

Results are displaying like this: [image]

My question is I want hide that duplicate area values and is there any short way to do  this (instead of repeating same code 4 times)?

**HTML CODE**

```
<div class="col-lg-6 footerArea">
                    <h3>Area</h3>
                                        <ul>
                        <li class="cat-item cat-item-360"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/aali/">A'ali</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-101"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/adhari-park/">Adhari Park</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-61"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/adliya/" title="Adliya">Adliya</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-355"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/airport/">Airport</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-367"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/airport-arrivals/">Airport Arrivals</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-479"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/airport-departure/">Airport Departure</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-102"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/al-aali-shopping-complex/">Al Aali Shopping Complex</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-4"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/al-areen/">Al Areen</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-368"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/al-hayat-centre/">Al Hayat Centre</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-365"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/american-alley-juffair/">American Alley Juffair</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-62"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/amwaj-islands/" title="Amwaj Islands">Amwaj Islands</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-390"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/arad/">Arad</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-430"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/bab-al-bahrain/">Bab Al Bahrain</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-63"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/bahrain-financial-harbour/" title="Bahrain Financial Harbour">Bahrain Financial Harbour</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-103"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/bahrain-mall/">Bahrain Mall</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-361"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/barbar/">Barbar</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-100"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/bcc/">BCC</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-480"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/bdf/">BDF</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-423"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/bfh-mall/">BFH Mall</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-65 current-cat"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/budaiya/" title="Budaiya">Budaiya</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-512"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/bukhuwara/">Bukhuwara</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-477"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/burhama/">Burhama</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-104"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/busaiteen/">Busaiteen</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-327"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/city-centre/">City Centre</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-372"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/country-mall/">Country Mall</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-427"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/daih/">Daih</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-67"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/diplomatic-area/" title="Diplomatic Area">Diplomatic Area</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-68"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/durrat-al-bahrain/" title="Durrat Al Bahrain">Durrat Al Bahrain</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-523"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/east-riffa/">East Riffa</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-395"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/enma-mall/">Enma Mall</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-356"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/exhibitions-avenue/">Exhibitions Avenue</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-71"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/gudaibiya/" title="Gudaibiya">Gudaibiya</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-467"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/hamad-town/">Hamad Town</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-72"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/hamala/" title="Hamala">Hamala</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-357"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/hidd/">Hidd</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-73"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/hoora/" title="Hoora">Hoora</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-328"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/isa-town/">Isa Town</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-533"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/janabiyah/">Janabiyah</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-366"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/jawad-dome-barbar/">Jawad Dome Barbar</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-525"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/jiblat-al-hibshi/">Jiblat Al Hibshi</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-396"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/jid-ali/">Jid Ali</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-6"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/juffair/">Juffair</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-74"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/mahooz/" title="Mahooz">Mahooz</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-96"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/manama/">Manama</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-75"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/maqsha/" title="Maqsha">Maqsha</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-425"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/marina-mall/">Marina Mall</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-384"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/moda-mall/">Moda Mall</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-76"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/muharraq/" title="Muharraq">Muharraq</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-359"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/nwaidrat/">Nwaidrat</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-397"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/oasis-mall/">Oasis Mall</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-362"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/ramli-mall/">Ramli Mall</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-77"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/ras-ruman/" title="Ras Ruman">Ras Ruman</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-107"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/reef-island/">Reef Island</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-481"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/reef-mall/">Reef Mall</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-401"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/reem-centre/">Reem Centre</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-78"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/riffa/" title="Riffa">Riffa</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-526"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/riffa-views/">Riffa Views</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-528"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/royal-bahrain-hospital/">Royal Bahrain Hospital</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-458"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/royal-golf-club/">Royal Golf Club</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-79"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/saar/" title="Saar">Saar</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-470"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/saar-mall/">Saar Mall</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-363"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/sakhir/">Sakhir</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-471"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/salmabad/">Salmabad</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-369"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/salmaniya/">Salmaniya</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-81"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/sanabis/" title="Sanabis">Sanabis</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-82"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/sanad/" title="Sanad">Sanad</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-482"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/saudi-causeway/">Saudi Causeway</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-83"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/seef/" title="Seef">Seef</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-534"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/seef-corner/">Seef Corner</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-105"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/seef-mall/">Seef Mall</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-342"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/seef-mall-muharraq/">Seef Mall – Muharraq</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-388"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/seef-tower/">Seef Tower</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-373"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/segaya/">Segaya</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-84"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/sehla/" title="Sehla">Sehla</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-85"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/sitra/" title="Sitra">Sitra</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-106"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/sitra-mall/">Sitra Mall</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-520"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/sugaiya/">Sugaiya</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-454"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/sultan-mall/">Sultan Mall</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-527"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/tala-island-amwaj/">Tala Island Amwaj</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-508"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/tala-plaza/">Tala Plaza</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-387"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/the-lagoon/">The Lagoon</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-538"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/the-walk/">The Walk</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-358"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/tubli/" title="Tubli">Tubli</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-386"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/umm-al-hassam/">Umm Al Hassam</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-398"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/university-of-bahrain/">University of Bahrain</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-472"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/wadi-mall/">Wadi Mall</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-463"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/west-riffa/">West Riffa</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-517"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/yateem-centre/">Yateem Centre</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-433"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/yum-yum-tree/">Yum Yum Tree</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-347"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/zallaq/">Zallaq</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-326"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/zayed-town/">Zayed Town</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-88"><a href="http://localhost:8888/guide/zinj/" title="Zinj">Zinj</a>
</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

**ERROR SCREENSHOT :**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use like below

```
            <div class="col-lg-6 footerArea">
        <h3>Area</h3>
        <?php           
                $orderby      = 'name';
                $show_count   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
                $pad_counts   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
                $hierarchical = 1;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
                $title        = '';
                $empty        = 0;            

                // your taxonomy name
                $tax = array("category","post_tag","topics");

                // get the terms of taxonomy
                $terms = get_terms( $tax,array(
                    'orderby'      => $orderby,
                    'order'     => 'ASC', 
                    'hide_empty'   => $empty,
                    'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
                    'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
                    'show_count'   => $show_count,
                ));

                $termArray = array();

                // loop through all terms
                foreach( $terms as $term ) {        
                    $termArray[$term->slug]['id']=  $term->term_id;
                    $termArray[$term->slug]['name']=  $term->name;                  
                    $termArray[$term->slug]['link']=  get_term_link( $term );
                }
        ?>

        <ul>
        <?php
            foreach( $termArray as $term ) {                    
                echo '<li><a href="'. $term['link'] .'">'. $term['name'].'</a></li>';
            }
        ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

**Screenshot**
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer , But still the area names are duplicating for example in my question you can see the image which is highlighted with red color border  .So i just want hide that multiple area names .

Comment: @user3744932, please form the area into a single array and remove duplicates

Comment: I did like this but it doesn't work to me , can you guide me how to do this please .  $taxonomyArray = array("therapy_area","hospitals_area","therapy_area","salonsandsaps_area");
 $arr1=array_unique($taxonomyArray);
        print_r($arr1);

Comment: @user3744932, All of the area are in single array?

Comment: it does not work for duplicate areas. Its only for reduce the $args3

Comment: okay , can you give me any example code to solve this issue please

Comment: Before get the  wp_list_categories( $args );  you should make a array in all list.

Comment: I would like to see your html script. your html like <ul><li></li></ul>, <ul><li></li></ul>, <ul><li></li></ul>

Comment: You are posting php script. I want see the html script. Copy from view source and post the html

Comment: I can see only one Manama. There is no duplicate

Comment: I need some more code for create different taxonomy. So I can?

Comment: I have uploaded the screenshot please check it

Comment: I removed duplicates by slug. so same taxanomy slug will be removed.

Comment: In your updated code some syntax error coming .Error shwoing in this line "  $terms = get_terms($tax, [".

Comment: Error message : "There is a syntax error on line 45"

Comment: $tax = array("category"); show contain available taxanomies

Comment: $tax = array("privateschool_area", "hospitals_area", "therapy_area", "salonsandsaps_area"); replace this line

Comment: yeah that values i changed it already but still same error :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128034/discussion-between-user3744932-and-vel).

Comment: Let us continue this discussion in chat.